# put a function of the controller inside another controller with angular

Tags: angularjs, controller

I need to put this function

```
function GraphsCtrl($scope, $http, $q){

$scope.chartExistencias = {

    dataSource: { 
        load: function () {
            var def = $.Deferred();
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: ng.api + '/llantas/graficos/'+1 }).success(function (data) {
                 for(var i = 0; i<data.data.length; i++){

                     totalEx = data.data[i].count + totalEx;

                 }
                 $scope.totalEx = totalEx;


                def.resolve(data.data);

            }); 

           return def.promise();

        }

    }
```

}

inside this controller

```
define([], function() {
return ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$utilities', '$appCache', '$q', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $utilities, $appcache, $q) {



}
```

which works for a specific view, the point is that this is my html

```
   <div ng-controller ='GraphsCtrl' >

      <div dx-chart='chartExistencias' id='chartExistencias' s   tyle="max-width:510px; min-width:400px; height:300px; float:left;"></div>

    </div>
```

and I'm using the ng controller, what can I do?

Comment: Why doesn't the controller have a name? What version of angular is this? Has there been a time when you wouldn't use module.controller to create a new controller?

Comment: .state('resumen', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: ng.TmplPath + "/index/main/resumen.html",
            controller: function($scope, $injector, $rootScope) {

                //
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loadBC', []);

                require([ng.JSPath + '/index/main/resumen'], function(ResumenCtrl) {
                    $injector.invoke(ResumenCtrl, this, {'$scope': $scope});
                });
            }
        })

Comment: The name is resumen.js

Comment: Well, you can use GraphsCtrl in your html since you defined it in global scope, assuming it's being included. But what are you trying to accomplish with your controller?

Comment: I have a controller per view, and my graphs are actually using the controller.js file but I need to put the graphs ctrl gunction or the scopes of every chart inside the controllers view